# Looper.getMainLooper() null on unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm trying to make unit test for a class that extends from a view and I'm getting a null pointer exception due to at some point in the parent class, it's trying to use `Looper.getMainLooper().thread` which actually is null. After trying to understand why the view initialisation was failing, throwing a NPE, I noticed that it seemed to be because `Looper.getMainLooper()`. How should I write unit test for a view that checks for main looper and where do tests executed on MockitoJUnitRunner are executed?

code example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)

  @Test
  fun `my test`(){

      val looper = Looper.getMainLooper()
      val myView = MycustomView(x,y,z)
  }
```

Comment: Any ideas, please?

Comment: If view gets harder to test it might be a good idea to think if it's not doing too much. This sounds like something that controller/presenter/something else should be doing and then you can just inject Looper into that object while creating it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a static mock.  [MockK](https://mockk.io/) is great for this and can be used with Mockito.

You can stub `thread` from the static `getMainLooper()` method using MockK this way:

```
mockkStatic(Looper::class)

val looper = mockk<Looper> {
    every { thread } returns Thread.currentThread()
}

every { Looper.getMainLooper() } returns looper

// run your tests

unmockkAll()
```